# How do I "break" out of an if/else statement?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, dry, break

I can't seem to figure out how to stop an if/else statement from going onto the next "answer" if the first answer is incorrect.

```
classic_house_tracks = ['Come on Now Baby', 'Follow Me', 'The Spirit']
puts "Who produced " + classic_house_tracks[1] + "?"
producer_input = gets.chomp.to_s
if producer_input == "Aly-Us" || producer_input == "aly-us" || producer_input == "Aly-us"
    puts "Yep, and are Aly-Us from Detroit or Chicago?"
else
    puts "Nope, wrong producer."
# break
# end
# that obviously didn't work.
end
```

(Feel free to help me DRY up my code as I am a newbie.) :) Thanks if 
    anyone can help!

Comment: Where is the loop you are trying to break out of?

Answer (score 1):

Using `return`  keyword, if `string` is returned then it will  exit the code.
Also you can make it DRY as below:

```
classic_house_tracks = [
  'Come on Now Baby', 
  'Follow Me', 
  'The Spirit'
] 
puts "Who produced #{classic_house_tracks[1]}?"
producer_input = gets.chomp.to_s
if producer_input.downcase == "aly-us"
  puts "Yep, and are Aly-Us from Detroit or Chicago?" 
else
  return "Nope, wrong producer."
end
```